# Is this possible to do with images in java?

Tags: java, swing

Is there any way I can print/show images on top of each other. The picture on top will always be positioned a little lower so that the one under will show partially. How can I decide which image is on top of what image? What layout lets me do this kind of positioning?

Is there any way that I can make a border appear on the image when I click it, and then move to (doesnt have to be animated, can be a "jump") where I click next inside the JFrame.

I've been trying to do this whole day now (I'm pretty new to swing), before I carry on I'd like to know if I'm trying something impossible.

So far I've been printing the images right on to the JFrame as JPanels... Inside the JPanel I add in the paintComponent(Graphics g) method: g.drawImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a Swing tutorial is in order.

What you're describing shouldn't be very hard. Instead of painting the images directly, load them up in `ImageIcons`, and pass those to `JLabels`. That way you can manipulate your images as `JComponents`, using layout managers, or direct coordinates by setting the layout to `null`. You can set the Z-Order with `setComponentZOrder` regardless of the layout you choose. You can draw borders by adding swing borders (see `BorderFactory`) to the JLabels. You can handle the manipulation with MouseListeners.

Comment: really want to thank you! it's going very good now with my assignment, thanks to you :P.. we've had no swing, and still we have to make a solitaire game :D

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Root Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). You may be able to do something with the Layered Pane or the Glass Pane. I would try the Layered Pane first.